# Question about Strong Minimum Principle

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, maxima-minima, maximum-principle

Denote the indicator function on a meausurable set $A$ as $\chi_A$.

On page 11 of the book *Regularity of Free Boundaries in Obstacle-type Problems*, the author states that:

Consider the problem (1)
$$\begin{cases}
\Delta u = f\chi_\Omega, & \text{in }B_r(x_0) \\
u = |∇u| = 0, & \text{on }B_r(x_0) \setminus Ω \\
u\ge 0, & \text{in }B_r(x_0) \\
\end{cases}$$
where $\Omega$ is a given open set and $x_0\in\partial\Omega$ is a given point. Then, **any solution $u$ to problem (1) is also a solution to problem (2), aka the obstacle problem**:
$$\begin{cases}
\Delta u = f\chi_{\{u>0\}}, & \text{in }B_r(x_0) \\
u\ge 0, & \text{in }B_r(x_0) \\
\end{cases}$$

**The author seems to imply that $B_r(x_0)\,\cap\,\Omega =\{u>0\}$. But how to prove it?**

Since $u\ge 0$ in problem (1), it seems to be some kind of (strong) minimum principle - $u(x)>\inf_{\partial(B_r(x_0)\,\cap\,\Omega)} u =0$. However, since $u$ is not harmonic ($f$ is not necessarily the zero function), I have no idea how to proceed.

---

I have tried considering the function $\tilde u(x)=u(x)-\frac{||f||_\infty+\epsilon}{2n}||x||^2$, where $\Delta \tilde u = f\chi_{\Omega}-(||f||_\infty+\epsilon)<0$ and thus $\tilde u$ does not attain any minimum in the interior.

However, this does not lead to any conclusion about $u$ being positive in the interior.